# SwiftUI Question: Place text underneath(outside) of list view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to place this information underneath my list. I don't want it to be included in the list but rather it should be displayed on the view background. Sort of like the old settings in iOS 6. I've tried placing my code snippets in different spots and removing stacks snd even changing what stacks I'm using and I cant figure it out. Heres my code and a screenshot:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsAboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // Top Section
            Section {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Spacer()
                        
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                            .shadow(radius: 2)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("PineGlade"))
                                                        
                        Image(systemName: "leaf.arrow.circlepath")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                             
                    }.cornerRadius(10)
                        
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Gardn")
                            .font(.system(size: 32))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("ShipsOfficer"))
                                                               
                        Text("OnlyOdds.co Labs")
                            .font(.system(size: 13))
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("ShipsOfficer"))
                    }
                        
                    Spacer()
                                
                }.padding()
                        
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsPrivacyView()) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Privacy Settings")
                                
                    }) {
                        SettingsCell(title: "Privacy", imgName: "eye.slash", clr: Color("PineGlade"))
                    }
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsNotificationsView()) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Notification Settings")
                                
                    }) {
                        SettingsCell(title: "Notifications", imgName: "bell", clr: Color("PineGlade"))
                    }
                }
            }
           
            // Technical Info
            HStack(spacing: 62) {
                Spacer()
                
                Text("V \(UIApplication.appVersion!)")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("ShipsOfficer"))
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    
                Text("Build  \(UIApplication.appBuild!)")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("ShipsOfficer"))
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    
                Spacer()
            }
                
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct SettingsAboutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsAboutView()
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    static var appVersion: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    static var appBuild: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the background color of the `version cell` to something like its not there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Footer. The [Section View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/3274272-init) takes Footer as ViewBuilder as argument.

```
Section(footer: Text("Your footer text")) {
    //Your Content here
}
```

You can pass `Text()` or create your own custom view.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed! I knew it was simple but couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: @PoonDopolis No problem. Had to read their documentation aswell, only knew it from old Objective C time, never have looked it up for SwiftUI.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the List in a VStack and put 
    Text(yourtext)

Under the list

Comment: I tried but I kept getting an error about my navigation bar title

Comment: The text is not shown when placing the Text like this.